# Разработать программу, имеющую графический интерфейс, которая позволяет считывать информацию из файла в соответствующие виджеты: Label, Entry, Text

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть код, который считывает с Entry и Text некий текст, который вводит пользователь, и записывает его в файл. Нужно создать функции для считывания и вывода из этих файлов в Entry, Text, Label.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def registration():
    global entry

def get_entry():
    s = txt.get()
    file = open("test.txt", "a")
    file.write(s)
    file.close()

def insert_text():
    s = input()
    text.insert(1.0, s)
 
 
def get_text():
    s = text.get(1.0, END)
    file = open("MyText.txt", "a")
    file.write(s)
    file.close()
 
 
def delete_text():
    text.delete(1.0, END)

window = Tk()
window.title("Лабораторная №7")
window.geometry('650x300')

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='Запись в файл через Entry')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab2, text='Запись в файл через Text')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

tab3 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab3, text='Чтение из файла через Entry')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

tab4 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab4, text='Чтение из файла через Text')
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

lbl = Label(tab1,text="Введите текст, который хотите записать в файл")  
lbl.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=170, pady=10)
 
txt = Entry(tab1,width=20)
txt.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=0, pady=10)

btn = Button(tab1, text="Записать в файл", command=get_entry)
btn.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=0, pady=10)
  
text = Text(tab2, width=30, height=5)
text.pack()

Button(tab2, text="Сохранить в файл",
       command=get_text).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(tab2, text="Очистить поле ввода",
       command=delete_text).pack(side=LEFT)
 
label = Label()
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Может есть какие-нибудь идеи, как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишите вот это (если я правильно Вас понял):

```
te=open('test.txt') #или надо MyText.txt вместо test.txt
Label(window, text=te.read()).pack()
```